# Why didn't Arthur kill Gary?

Tags: joker

In [*Joker*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7286456/?ref_=nm_flmg_t_9_act), when Arthur's former co-workers come to visit him, why does he let Gary leave

> after killing Randall?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He only kills people who *"weren't nice"* to him. He even says this directly to Gary as he unlocks the door [4:00 in this clip]

> You were the only one that was ever nice to me.

Randall threw him under the bus earlier on the gun incident, which lost Arthur his job. Ref: [Why did Randall say that Arthur/Joker tried to buy a gun from him?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104978/why-did-randall-say-that-arthur-joker-tried-to-buy-a-gun-from-him)  We see clear evidence of this through the movie, by the ones we do see him kill - Randall, the 'Wall Street guys', his mother, Murray and almost certainly the psychiatrist.
Gary never did anything directly to hurt him.
You could compare this to Sophie's fate - she similarly never hurt Arthur, even when he surprised her by being in her apartment. Ref: [Did Arthur kill his imaginary girlfriend - the one that lived in his apartment?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106912/did-arthur-kill-his-imaginary-girlfriend-the-one-that-lived-in-his-apartment)